# All Language support font in java JTextArea on windows

Tags: java, windows

Can one use a font supporting all languages in `JTextArea` on java and windows   platform? I searched on google but did not find any help.

```
 textArea = new JTextArea();
 textArea.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 12));
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you are asking. Please try to explain what it is you want to achieve and where you're stuck.

Comment: @germi I think he wants to allow inputs not just in english but also other languages in windows platform.

Comment: @Rafiq do you have any specific language which you have in mind?

Comment: A font is the specific way glyphs (letters, digits, special characters,...) are formed. This has nothing to do with language, although some fonts may vary with their support for different alphabets (e.g. roman, greek, cyrillic,...)

Comment: I want all Language (Hindi, Telugu, Bengali, Arabic,Chinese etc.) support in JTexrArea input field  in java on windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you need a Unicode. For all languages such a font might be in the order of 20 MB.

You may supply the font in your application. What is needed is to register the font (i.a. with Windows).

```
//Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("code2000.ttf"))
Font font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,
    getResourceAsStream("/code2000.ttf"))
GraphicsEnvironment genv = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
genv.registerFont(font);
```

There is Arial Unicode MS, but that is not free. However there are sufficient free full Unicode fonts.

Comment: I'm pretty sure registering the font is not strictly necessary, unless other code intends to refer to it by name (such as in a Font constructor, in one of the Font.getFont methods, TextAttribute.FAMILY, StyleConstants.Family, or in CSS in an HTML-enabled Swing component).  For a single JTextArea, the new Font object can just be passed to textArea.setFont.

Comment: @VGR yes, the name lookup goes for logical font names (old java), system font names and registered font names. The latter needed for application provided fonts.